# Excel find some value in column and place a value to next colof the matched row

Tags: excel

There are three columns

```
col1= consignee name
col2= port name
col3= country name.
```

i want to set a col3 country name ="USA" where in col2 port name="Los Angeles" in excel.

Answer (score 0):

From what you shared this is solution:

```
=IF(B1="Los Angeles","USA","Other")
```